# Batch file conditions - Execute next statement only if FOR loop is true

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I built/adapted a script to uninstall any previous version of Java before it install a new one. The script goes as follows;

1 - Uninstall any previous version of JAVA

```
SET regVar32=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WinDOws\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
SET regVar64=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\WinDOws\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

SET myCMD=REG QUERY %regVar32% /s /f *java*
FOR /f " usebackq delims={} tokens=2" %%i IN (`%myCMD%`) DO ( msiexec /x {%%i} /qn /norestart )

SET myCMD=REG QUERY %regVar64% /s /f *java*
FOR /f " usebackq delims={} tokens=2" %%i IN (`%myCMD%`) DO ( msiexec /x {%%i} /qn /norestart )
```

2 - Clean registry

3 - Clean files and folders

4 - install new version of JAVA

The problem is that the script doesn't have any condition and if the routine 1 doesn't find anything to uninstall it will continue to execute the others subroutines.
What I want to be able to do is that if routine number 1 above doesn't have anything to uninstall `GOTO :INSTALL` and install the new JAVA without running 2 and 3.

I hope I explained myself clear enough ;-) thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the "above" you refer to? What condition are you evaluating and what results do you expect?

Comment: What I need is to evaluate the 1st routine. If the 1st routine doesn't have anything to uninstall proceed to :INSTALL without going through subroutines 2 and 3 (Clean).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally was able to get it right with some help from you guys here. Here is how it ended up;

```
ECHO -------------------------------------------------------
ECHO UNISTALL ANY PREVIOUS VERSIONS OF JAVA 32 Bit
ECHO -------------------------------------------------------
SET uinstallState=false
SET jver="Java 7"
SET regVar32=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
SET myCMD=REG QUERY %regVar32% /s /f %jver%
FOR /f " usebackq delims={} tokens=2" %%i IN (`%myCMD%`) DO (
 SET uinstallState=true
 ECHO Uninstall Key: {%%i}
 ECHO Condition: %uinstallState%
  )

ECHO -------------------------------------------------------
ECHO UNISTALL ANY PREVIOUS VERSIONS OF JAVA 64 Bit
ECHO -------------------------------------------------------
SET uinstallState=false
SET jver="Java 7"
SET regVar64=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
SET myCMD=REG QUERY %regVar64% /s /f %jver%
FOR /f " usebackq delims={} tokens=2" %%i IN (`%myCMD%`) DO (
 SET uinstallState=true
 ECHO Uninstall Key: {%%i}
 ECHO Condition: %uinstallState%
  )
IF %uinstallState% NEQ true GOTO INSTALL
```

So now it will Skip the subroutine 2 and 3 and go straight to INSTALL if there is nothing to uninstall. :-)

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Interesting! First, you _copied_ the basic part of my answer in order to "develop" the yours, but now you unselect the former Best Answer (the mine) to select "your" answer... **`:(`** Didn't you knew that selecting an own answer will _not_ give you rep points?

Answer (score 0):

```
(for /f .... do (msiexec .... )) || goto :install
```

If the `for` command does not find any line to process, it raises errorlevel. Using conditional execution you can detect it and directly jump to the required label.

Comment: Same as above. I've tried;

`SET myCMD=REG QUERY %regVar32% /s /f *java 9* FOR /f " usebackq delims={} tokens=2" %%i IN (`%myCMD%`) DO ( ECHO {%%i} ) || goto :install`

And it will goto to install anyways.

Comment: @Heyvoon, you are missing the parenthesis around the full `for /f` (see the posted code skeleton) and the quotes in `/f "*java 9*"` because there is a space in the string.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you want to know if the two `for` commands in step 1-Uninstall processed any file. You may do that this way:

```
SET anyFileUninstalled=false

SET myCMD=REG QUERY %regVar32% /s /f *java*
FOR /f " usebackq delims={} tokens=2" %%i IN (`%myCMD%`) DO ( 
   msiexec /x {%%i} /qn /norestart
   SET anyFileUninstalled=true
)

SET myCMD=REG QUERY %regVar64% /s /f *java*
FOR /f " usebackq delims={} tokens=2" %%i IN (`%myCMD%`) DO ( 
   msiexec /x {%%i} /qn /norestart
   SET anyFileUninstalled=true
)

if %anyFileUninstalled% neq true goto install
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the FOR /f statement execute anyways. So it will be always true. I tried. Thank you.

Comment: Hum, err... It seems to me that the method you used in [your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539811/batch-file-conditions-execute-next-statement-only-if-for-loop-is-true/29559824#29559824) is the same I presented here (you just changed my `anyFileUninstalled` variable name by `uinstallState`). Perhaps I missed something? :/